# Seeking CSMapMaker (QGIS Plugin) equivalent for ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, software-recommendations, slope, curvature

I'm looking for a tool or script or set of operations to mimic the output from a certain QGIS plugin called [CSMapMaker](https://github.com/waigania13/CSMapMaker), wherein curvature, slope, and a gaussian filtered DEM are overlain one another in an optimal way to view geomorphic features from DEMs.  The result is like the attached image, I wasn't able to determine what this procedure is called, if it has a name, and/or find anything on the web that was similar for ArcGIS.

I need to apply this tool to larger datasets (2-4GB) and I get python errors in QGIS if my datasets are too big, so I thought I would look for a tool that could be used in the ArcGIS environment, possibly allowing me to do the same thing on larger DEMs.

I've attached a sample of the output from the QGIS plugin here.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By searching for "CSMapMaker", I found [this site](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ja&u=https://www.geospatial.jp/ckan/dataset/csmapmaker&prev=search) (originally in Japanese) that has "software for ArcGIS" called CSMapMaker. I make absolutely no claims about the legitimateness/safety of installing and running this software.

The description for this software calls it "Automatic CS stereo drawing software for ArcGIS." So, going on the hypothesis that the image you posted is a "CS stereo drawing", I searched for for "arcgis cs stereo."

I found this ArcGIS guide: [Viewing the display in stereo using red and blue anaglyphs](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/arcscene/viewing-the-display-in-stereo-using-red-and-blue-anaglyphs.htm). It has instructions, "to configure ArcScene to display the 3D view in a stereo viewing mode that works with glasses with red and blue lenses."

So my guess is that the QGIS CSMapMaker plugin creates images that would look 3D if you were wearing the kind of 3D glasses with red and blue lenses. This is called an [Anaglyph 3D image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_3D).

> Anaglyph 3D is the name given to the stereoscopic 3D effect achieved by means of encoding each eye's image using filters of different (usually chromatically opposite) colors, typically red and cyan.

You can create Anaglyph 3D maps in ArcMap with the 3D Analyst license (so no need to install any sketch 3rd party software).

[Here](https://stereo.gsfc.nasa.gov/classroom/glasses.shtml) are instructions for making your own 3D glasses.

Comment: It's actually not a 3D stereo image, it's certain stacked layers with transparency and colored. Elevation, curvature and slope, but they're set to red and blue for optimum viewing of surfaces. I'll check out that software though, thanks!

Comment: That link to the software was what I needed, essentially its the same process as the CSMapMaker plugin for QGIS except done as a toolbox for ArcMap.

Comment: Did you figure out what "CS" stands for? Both plugin descriptions say they create "CS stereo drawings" but they don't define "CS."

Comment: Yeah, it's curvature and slope - calculated from the DEMs, common analysis for landforms.